# Mail infrastructure with dovecot proxy

Tags: postfix, proxy, dovecot

[image]

Hi there, I try make to work my mail infrastructure, but i have problem with this. I tryed with NGINX but i can read mail from thunderbird, but i can't send. It's problem with authentication.

My second plan is use dovecot configure to proxy imap/pop3 [dovecot proxy mysql](https://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields/Proxy). It's really nice, working like I expect, but what i really do with postfix?

I want authenticate my user in mx1 or mx2, 
How i can do that? Configure postfix using sasl to dovecot? Or configure postfix to be relay?

I can connect from mx1 with telnet to for example port 110 and see mails. But with postfix have a lite problem. Mayby this is a solution [Dovecot imapc proxy](https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/ImapcProxy)?

I have two imaps server with half/half users, this is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If your dovecot is already configured to provide authentication, configure something like this for dovecot

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
```

and make postfix use the socket

```
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
```